# Inline Table with Dynammic row add and post to sql using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Hey can anyone tell me how can i make table with add delet update row with adding  data to mysql using php
im new to php so i want fetch table from db and show into table with option add edit delet option while add row option will be dyannmic and can add row in between the the row of table

Answer (score 0):

Example for Delete:
index.php`include('conn.php'); $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from`table`");

```
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?><form action="" method="POST">
         **<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ">Delete</a>**
       </form> 
   <?php      
  }
```

delete.php:
  `<?php $id=$_POST['id']; include('conn.php'); mysqli_query($conn,"delete from`user `where id='**$id**'"); header('location:main.php'); ?>`

explanation:
Carries a variable with the link and creates a new query with it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QS0W.jpg

Comment: can you tell me how can i add row in between row and post it to db

Answer (score 0):

```
 example for insert
 add.php
    <form method="post">
     <textarea rows="5" name="**big_text**"></textarea>

    </form>
    add-edit.php
     $textarea=$_POST['big_text'];
     mysqli_query($conn,"insert into `table` (text) values  ('$textarea')");
     header('location:add.php');
```